# How to place views inside Coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I need to use `Coordinatorlayout` in order to get the `layout_behaviour` attr to hide `FAB` on scroll.

Normally I would just placing my FAB in the bottom - end, but this time I implemented expandable fab and I find it very hard to place 4 FABS one above each other in Coordinatorlayout .

Any ideas what can I do?
I don't mind get solution either way(handle fab hiding on webview scroll below API 23 without Coordinatorlayout OR place the fabs one above each other correctly in `Coordinatorlayout`)

Currently this is my `ConstraintLayout:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fab1" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fab2" />
    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAB's must be direct child of the coordinator layout

you can use

```
 app:layout_anchor="@id/****"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
```

attributes for this

for your case, you can change the xml like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab1"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: In fact the use of huge margins is what scared me the most, there is no way around this?